# How do I generate an array with N rows and N columns with each element being a 2 row single column zero matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate an array ( a matrix would also do the job ) with N rows and N columns, such that each element of the array is a 2 row-single column zero matrix. Please feel free to provide a solution using matrices. Thank You

Comment: Feel free to check out the docs - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Comment: You just need np.zeros: `np.zeros([n,n,2,1])`

Comment: What do you mean by 'matrices'?  There is a `numpy` constructor `np.matrix`, but we are discouraged from using it in new code.  What `dtype` do you expect?  What `shape`?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out before, you might have a look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) and [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html). Try to combine

```
mat=np.zeros((n,n))
```

and

```
dt = np.dtype((np.float, (2,1)))
```

Comment: Yes, do try `np.zeros(n,n)` yourself, and show us the result!  `np.zeros((3,3),dtype=np.dtype((np.float, (2,1)))) ` produces a (3,3,2,1) shape, same as `np.zeros((3,3,2,1))` would.

Comment: very nice and detailed answer!